# Imagemagick - PDF to Jpeg/Raster texture issue

Tags: php, pdf, imagemagick, raster, image-conversion

I am using `imagemagick/php` to make a jpeg file from a PDF.

Input PDF file:
[PDF-file](http://keysymmetrics.com.au/floor-plan.pdf)

Output Jpeg file:

[image: output jpeg]
[Jpeg-file](http://keysymmetrics.com.au/floor-plan.jpg)

The textures on the output file look wrong near the bottom. This is the same result if I make a PNG also. I have tired different floor plans, other textures play up also in a similar way.

**PHP code**

```
$im = new Imagick();
$im->setResolution( 300, 300 ); 
$im->readImage( $input_path );
$im->setImageFileName($output_path);
$im->writeImage();
```

**Server Config**

```
PHP Version 5.3.5
ImageMagick 6.4.8
```

Thank you.

Comment: Don't use jpeg for non organic images(this wont solve your problem, but will make the viewers eye hurt less)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like ImageMaigck handles opacity in embedded images in PDFs incorrectly. I am not familiar enough with ImageMagick to have a solution for you, but [it is discussed here in their documentation](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/formats/#ps) -- perhaps there is an option you can change to improve things.